# Append one MP4 file to other MP4 file using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I would like to concatenate TWO MP4 files without re-encoding. Both have same characteristics.

As suggested on some forums, I use a following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -hide_banner -loglevel info -f concat -safe 0 -i "R:\VTS_01_1.mp4" -c copy "R:\JointVideoFile.mp4"
```

Here I modified it slightly. Forums suggest creating a temporary file with a list of names of files to concatenate. I have only two files and do not want to create a temporary file, so I modified this command slightly by specifying file name directly.

So I want FFMPEG to take an existing `JointVideoFile.mp4` and append an existing `VTS_01_1.mp4` to its end.

Executing the above command causes an error:

> [concat @ 00000000004b08c0] Line 4: unknown keyword 'ftypisom'
> R:\VTS_01_1.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input

`ftypisom` is the first text tag in my MP4 files.

FFMPEG expects a text list file when using `concat` and interprets characters in MP4 file as a text.

How to make it work without a list?

Comment: Short version: the `-f concat` method **requires** a list in a text file, you cannot avoid that. But there are other concatenation methods in ffmpeg, and a must-read is: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Answer (score 1):

Something like this shoud work if both videos really have same characteristics like frame width, hight, rate:

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat list.txt -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Where list.txt should look something like this:

```
file 'video_1.mp4"
file 'video_2.mp4"
```

Using a oneliner:

```
echo file 'JointVideoFile.mp4'>>List.txt&echo file 'VTS_01_1.mp4'>>List.txt& ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i List.txt -c copy output.mp4& del /q List.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It produces an exact copy of first video from the list.

Comment: what is your OS? Try the other option I just added...

Comment: My OS is Windows 7 64 bit. What is this added other option?

Comment: Looks like there was an errror on my first try, can you try the other option now?

Comment: I got an error: Streamcopy requested for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.

Comment: Inline concat sems to work only with TS format

Comment: please see updated answer

Comment: At the end it seems that you are ending up with an external file list, which is what the OP wanted to possibly avoid...

Comment: It works with the list, but I would like to do this without one (see the question).

Comment: I looks simple but I can't think of a way of doing this without creating the temporary file. Would it help if you could do it all with a oneliner? Creating the temp file, running ffmpeg and deleting the temp file?

Comment: In Linux/bash there are some ways that use bash features, but I don't think the same is pssible in Windows batch (but I'm no specialist in Windows batch)